# MySQL list queries equal to multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to list people from California, Los Angeles who are male or female but I don't want all males and females from California to be listed.

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE state='california' 
    AND city='los_angeles' 
    AND gender='male' OR gender='female'
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE city='los_angeles' 
    AND gender='male' OR gender='female'
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I dont get it. 1st you write you want 
  All PPL that are Male/Female from California and Los Angeles,
And then you dont want PPL that are Male/Female from California to be listed?  So you may just get ALL PPL from Los Angeles....

Comment: So for that ``SELECT * from people where state='Los Angeles' and gender in ('male', 'female')``    you may also use   `(gender = 'male' or gender = 'female')`.

Comment: Parentheses are your friend

Answer (score 3):

More compact:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE state='california' 
               AND city='los_angeles' AND gender in ('male','female')");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you combine `AND` and `OR` operators you have to remember that `AND` has higher precedence. So you have to use parenthesis:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE state='california' 
          AND city='los_angeles' AND (gender='male' OR gender='female')");
```

Your query returned all males from Los Angeles. It also returned all females (no matter from which city)

see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) link for details about `AND/OR` operators
and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/html/A85397_01/operator.htm#997691) link for operator precedence

Comment: Additionally, the `IN` shorthand may be easier to understand.